# Move lines from file with delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, text, split, strip

Lets say I have file with some exception like

```
1.2.3.4/24#/* 208-01 | 208-02 | 
                         ** | test |
                         ** test2 */

5.6.7.8/27#/* just a comment */
9.10.11.12/32#/* comment
                         ** part of comment above */
11.23.13.14/32#/* comment */
```

As you can see the comment have a start_delimiter **#/*** and end_delimiter ***/**

I basically want the comment between start and end delimiter in one line

```
1.2.3.4/24#/* 208-01 | 208-02 | ** | test |** test2 */
5.6.7.8/27#/* just a comment */
9.10.11.12/32#/* comment ** comment */
11.23.13.14/32#/* comment */
```

Above is just snapshot of huge txt file that i have.
Strategy is reading line by line save in somehow the line between #/* and */ and move in one line. Any idea if somehting similar is possible in python?

Answer (score 0):

For the given examples, you might use a pattern to match the parts that have multiple lines, and then remove the newlines from the match.

```
#/\*(?!.*\*/).*(?:\n(?!.*\*/).*)*\n.*\*/
```

- `#/\*` Match the starting part
- `(?!.*\*/)` Assert no closing part in the current line
- `.*` Match the whole line
- `(?:\n(?!.*\*/).*)*` Optionally match all lines that do not contain a closing part
- `\n.*\*/` Match a newline and the closing part

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wL9PCA/1)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"#/\*(?!.*\*/).*(?:\n(?!.*\*/).*)*\n.*\*/"


s = ("1.2.3.4/24#/* 208-01 | 208-02 | \n"
            "                         ** | test |\n"
            "                         ** test2 */\n\n"
            "5.6.7.8/27#/* just a comment */\n"
            "9.10.11.12/32#/* comment\n"
            "                         ** part of comment above */\n"
            "11.23.13.14/32#/* comment */")
s = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: re.sub(r"\n", "", x.group()), s)
print(s)
```

Output

```
1.2.3.4/24#/* 208-01 | 208-02 |                          ** | test |                         ** test2 */

5.6.7.8/27#/* just a comment */
9.10.11.12/32#/* comment                         ** part of comment above */
11.23.13.14/32#/* comment */
```

If you want to remove the empty line in between, you can match all newlines that are not followed by a non whitespace char for example

```
#/\*(?!.*\*/).*(?:\n(?!.*\*/).*)*\n.*\*/\n*(?!\S)
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5doqXn)